# Can I turn to Dark Mode only for specific apps in macOS Mojave?

Tags: mojave, macos

The new macOS Mojave Dark Mode function makes **all** of Apple's built-in apps get the Dark Mode treatment, that is Safari, Mail, Contacts, Calendar, Reminders, Notes, Maps, Photos, Messages, FaceTime, iTunes, Apple Books, etc.

However, is it possible to **selectively** activate Dark Mode, i.e.,  only for a specific subset of apps? For instance, what if I want to keep Safari in Light Mode and turn Finder to Dark Mode instead? Am I somehow allowed to do that?

Comment: I really hope this becomes possible. I'd like to be able to set Terminal to Dark Mode as is done in ElementaryOS

Comment: Is just using a dark profile in Terminal really all that different? (Yes, I know the title bar and tabs are still light, but they're not exactly prominent, especially if none of your other apps are dark.)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There's a command that works for this:

```
defaults write <Bundle-Identifier> NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool yes
```

It's explained here: https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/exclude-app-dark-mode-macos-mojave/

If you don't know the app's bundle id, you can query it using AppleScript, which you can run from the command line with `osascript`:

```
osascript -e 'id of app "<App-Name>"'
```

Comment: `defaults write com.apple.iTunes NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool yes` didn't work for me :( macOS 10.14.4

Comment: Irony is I need to disable it for Apple script editor `defaults write com.apple.ScriptEditor2 NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool yes`

Comment: How do you enable the dark mode back on? 

This works perfectly, but I cannot switch to the entire dark mode now as some of the preferences were probably rewritten.

Comment: Thank you, this also works on macOS 11 (Big Sur).

Comment: @JoshE. it should be possible to undo the setting with: `defaults delete <Bundle-Identifier> NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance`

Comment: This does not work with Big Sur 11.6

Answer (score 18):

More free options include [Gray app](https://github.com/zenangst/Gray/) and [NightOwl](https://nightowl.kramser.xyz/). Both can be installed using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
brew install gray
brew install nightowl
```

Comment: to me definitely the perfect solution

Comment: What is the list item in Gray app for the mode of the menu bar? I managed to set everything except that.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:**

As others have pointed out, this app seems no longer available.

---

I've been using [LightsOff](https://gumroad.com/l/lightsoff/) for a couple of days now, seems to work very well.

It does "switch" between modes when you open an app that you have excluded and you can actually see the switching which is a bit of a downside.

Comment: I'd rather prefer a build-in option for that. Anyways, this app seems to do the job. There are some bugs to be fixed though (e.g., when opening an app in Light Mode, it flashes to Dark Mode first for a fraction of second).

Comment: Would be nice if Apple included it but this is the closest thing I guess.

Comment: Note that it switches the _entire_ MacOS system to Dark Mode when the application is active, not just the specific app.

Comment: Doesn’t work anymore, Mac OS 10.15.6 (19G2021)

Comment: No longer works, and the link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't there be a new alternative for this command based on early betas (see below):

`defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSWindowDarkChocolate -bool true`

Answer (score 1):

Using Safari 17.1 and macOS 14.1.1 (maybe working on other version but untested), you can :

1. Right click the page and select "Inspect Element".
2. Under "Elements" click the "Apparence" icon and you can choose "Colour scheme"

[image: How to change apparence in Safari]

This is very useful for developers when you want to test one page on a specific mode, without changing the mode of your OS.

Answer (score -1):

I think the method used to enable app specific light/dark mode has been disabled in 10.14.2